# Binding value in array at specific index in a repeat.for

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I will try to be clear in my question. I have a "repeat.for" in my HTML

```
<div repeat.for="category of categories" class="flex-form-group">
     <label class="flex-col-4">
        ${category.code}
     </label>
     <div class="flex-col-sm-6">
       <dropdownlist style="min-width:200px" model-name="valueCategory" filter="category_id eq ${category.id}"
                                fields="id,value" display-field="value" id-field="id" value.bind='valueContract[$index}]'>
                                <data-template>${value}</data-template>
       </dropdownlist>
     </div>
 </div>
```

My problem is in the "dropdownlist" component. I'm trying to bind the value of this component into an array. I would like to bind the value in the "valueContract" array and to the index of the repeat.for loop but I can't do it.
The error message is as follows :

> ERROR [app-router] Error: Parser Error: Missing expected token ] at column 21 in expression [valueContract[$index}]]

Comment: Shouldn't it be `${index}` instead of `$index}`?

Comment: It should be `$index` instead of `$index}` . Stupid question, just an oversight, sorry and thank's @Pointy :)